# Generate n appointments in the next m months

Tags: java, api, date

I work with an API where I need to write code to generate `n` appointment dates in the coming `m` months (from today). For the purpose, I write a Random date generator class provided.

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Random;
public class RandomDate {


    private final Random random;

    private final Date currentDate;
    private final int months;

    public RandomDate(Random random, Date currentDate, int months) {

        this.random = random;
        this.currentDate = currentDate;
        this.months = months;
    }

    public Date getRangeEndDate() {

    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

    calendar.setTimeInMillis(this.currentDate.getTime());
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, this.months * 30);

    return new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
}

public Date generateRandomDate(Date endDate) {

    int start = (int) this.currentDate.toLocalDate().toEpochDay();
    int end = (int) endDate.toLocalDate().toEpochDay();

    long randomDay = start + random.nextInt(end - start);
    return Date.valueOf(LocalDate.ofEpochDay(randomDay));
}

}
```

Is the code looks good and can we do it more elegantly?

Comment: The question is edited and made concise after the downvote

Comment: This question would be a better fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), not StackOverflow.

Comment: @LeoAso I will move it soon to the Code review. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I can't delete the question as you have been contributed by commenting.

Comment: You don't have to delete the question since it has been answered - just next time you have a "How can I make this code better?" question, consider code review instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't look good, because you are using time classes from 3 different packages (java.sql, java.time and java.util).

You should use only java.time classes, then convert the result to what ever you need (print, persist, ...).

Comment: The issue is I used the `java.sql.Date` class for the rest of the code and I have to go through it. This was the primary purpose to post the question. However, if this is not eligible here, I will move it to Code review soon as possible.

Comment: I can't delete the question as you have been contributed by writing an answer :|

Answer (score 0):

I updated the code with only using the `java.time.LocalDate`

```
public class RandomDate {

    private final LocalDate today;

    private final Random random;
    private final int months;


    public RandomDate(Random random, int months) {

        this.today = LocalDate.now();

        this.random = random;
        this.months = months;
    }


    public LocalDate getRangeEndDate() {

        LocalDate rangeEndDay = this.today.plusDays(this.months * 30);
        return rangeEndDay;
    }

    public LocalDate generateRandomDate(LocalDate endDate) {

        int start = (int) this.today.toEpochDay();
        int end = (int) endDate.toEpochDay();

        long randomDay = start + random.nextInt(end - start);
        return LocalDate.ofEpochDay(randomDay);
    }


    public LocalDate getToday() {
        return today;
    }

    public Random getRandom() {
        return random;
    }

    public int getMonths() {
        return months;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof RandomDate)) return false;
        RandomDate that = (RandomDate) o;
        return getMonths() == that.getMonths() &&
                Objects.equals(getToday(), that.getToday()) &&
                Objects.equals(getRandom(), that.getRandom());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(getToday(), getRandom(), getMonths());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RandomDate{" +
                "today=" + today +
                ", random=" + random +
                ", months=" + months +
                '}';
    }}
```